# KCL equation considering the leakage current

Tags: circuit-analysis, kirchhoffs-laws, leakage-current

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f6OH4a.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

In the schematics shown here I want to find out the potential at Va and Vb nodes with assuming a constant leakage current Ileak flowing at node Vb.
I want to write KCL equations for the nodes.
To start with for node Va : (Va-V1)/R1 + (Va/R4)+(Va-Vb)/R2 = 0
                  node Vb : (Vb-Va)/R2 + Vb / R5 - Ileak + (Vb-V2)/R3 = 0 and for leakage current I considered the superposition theorem and got Ileak=Vb/((R6||R5)+R2)||(R6||R3)); I am really not sure how to go ahead writing the equation taking the leakage current into consideration..

Comment: Are we certain that the constant-current leak has no effect on Va?  From my viewpoint, 28V/3(Kohm)=9.3 & 15V/1(Kohm)=15, so 9.3/(15+9.3)=3.1/8.1  (~0.383A) of the current through Ileak should be coming from source V1 (which would doubtless have an effect on a voltage reading @ Va) ;)

Comment: Please note that I did round a few numbers in my calculations there, so you may want to recalculate using higher precision for your "final answer."

Comment: yes the effect is certainly there, I wanted the equation to have the leakage current maybe in the form of superposition theorem put in as KCL equation and then calculate the voltage at the nodes...or any other suggestion to account for the leakage current in KCL form would be helpful..

Comment: Consider the voltage on a 1k resistor with a leakage through it of 1A.

Comment: It would be helpful if the KCL equations could be suggested for each node..I am just looking for an approach to write the KCL for circuit having constant leakage current.. :)

Comment: What have you tried for the KCL equations at Vb? Your equation for Va looks good, the equation for Vb merely has four terms instead of three: remember that you are writing down all the currents leaving or entering a given node.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are writing a sum of currents this is quite straightforward:

Vb: sum of all currents leaving that node

which can be written as

Vb: (Vb-Va)/R2 + Vb / R5 + Ileak + (Vb-V2)/R3 = 0

this can be rewritten as

Vb: (Vb-Va)/R2 + Vb / R5 + (Vb-V2)/R3 = -Ileak

Comment: but as commented earlier how the current equations would account for the effect of leakage current for node Va and Vb ? I mean how the equations for nodes Va and Vb look like since the equations  Va : (Va-V1)/R1 + (Va/R4)+(Va-Vb)/R2 = 0 ;Vb: (Vb-Va)/R2 + Vb / R5 + Ileak + (Vb-V2)/R3 = 0 doesn't give the correct picture...the values obtained after calculation is not as per the simulations

Comment: The current has no *direct* impact on Va, only on Vb. It affects the node voltage Va only since there is a different current through R2.

Comment: Mario - It's usually better to help someone figure out "homework type" questions on their own, rather than just giving a solution answer. @Dharam  Please show us your work so far for Vb (as suggested bu uint128_t), then point out exactly where you're unsure of how to apply the effect of Ileak to 1/both equations.

Comment: @KV5ROB. You are right. I think the poster had a problem dealing with a current source using nodal analysis. Therefore I considered an example for Vb as the most helpful way to show this.

Comment: my equations were like this node Va :(Va-V1)/R1 + (Va/R4)+(Va-Vb)/R2 = 0 ;Vb :(Vb-Va)/R2 + Vb / R5 - Ileak + (Vb-V2)/R3 = 0 and for leakage current I considered the superposition theorem and got Ileak=Vb/((R6||R5)+R2)||(R6||R3));I substituted the values for Ileak but I am getting confused here if I put the value Ileak = 1A then I get very high value but if I put the ileak value as calculated in terms of resistors and Vb I get values as Vb=4V and Va =12V...As per simulation vb should be 20.5mV and Va=11.2V

Comment: @Dharam Please edit that information into your original question.

Comment: There is no need to use superposition, since you can include the current in your nodal equations. The current is leaving the node, therefore it should be +Ileak. So the current is already there, you must not account for it a second time. And 1A is very high. The resistors at that node are on the order of 1kOhm, so a voltage in the range of 1kV has to be expected. Maybe some typo?

Comment: @ Mario but it's constant leakage current..if I put leakage only for node vb equation the values calculated are waya way up the measured in simulation..Also the circuit is using some random values which I created to understand the concept in a better way :P

Answer (score 0):

The problem was I had put unrealistic leakage current which the V1 and V2 could not source. Hence need to values in uA or mA,These two equations would suffice Va : (Va-V1)/R1 + (Va/R4)+(Va-Vb)/R2 = 0 node Vb : (Vb-Va)/R2 + Vb / R5 + Ileak + (Vb-V2)/R3 = 0